# contextpath is not setting in url when jsp to servelt is calling

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, oauth-2.0, gitlab

I have a maven web project called

```
gitlab.configuration
```

so the project path should be

```
http://localhost:8080/gitlab.configuration/
```

There is jsp file and it contains "a" html tag. when it is clicked I will be redirected to a predifined callback url. which is

```
http://localhost:8080/gitlaboslcadaptor/oauth/callback
```

but instead of above url the correct url should be

```
http://localhost:8080/gitlab.configuration/gitlaboslcadaptor/oauth/callback
```

.

my question is why it is not setting this contextpath ?

here I attached some of images as well.

please look in the images for what I'm saying if you don't clear.

entryPointForOauth2caller.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Oauth2caller</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container d-flex h-100">
    <div class="row align-self-center w-100">
        <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
            <div class="jumbotron text-center">
               <!-- <form action="https://gitlab.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=153c017c0f33d32abfb8b950983dcfce0cbe7ba49751033c0626c4f00f51ac72&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/gitlaboslcadaptor/oauth2/callback&response_type=code&state=941891abc&scope=api+read_user+read_registry+sudo+openid+profile+email" method="get">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">MakeAuthorize</button>
                </form> -->
                <a href="https://gitlab.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=153c017c0f33d32abfb8b950983dcfce0cbe7ba49751033c0626c4f00f51ac72&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/gitlaboslcadaptor/oauth2/callback&state=941891abc&scope=api+read_user+read_registry+sudo+openid+profile+email">Authorize</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Oauth2ProviderServlet.java (servlet class)

```java
package com.persistent.unite.oslc4j.gitlab.security.oauth2;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Oauth2ProviderServlet
 */

@WebServlet("/gitlaboslcadaptor/oauth2/callback/*")
public class Oauth2ProviderServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Oauth2ProviderServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig)
     */
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("init mehtod in provider");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String code = request.getParameter("code");
        String state = request.getParameter("state");
        System.out.println("call back url's code for access token: " + code);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("dopost mehtod called.");
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

if callback url called then my servlet doget method at least should print something. but it seems my serlvet won't call at all.

here I attached images which im getting.

[image: ui for displaying first gitlab endpoint for oauth2 authorization]

after clicking the "authorize" link following output im getting.

[image: first endpoint redirect to callback url]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging I found the issue. 
callback url is not properly configured.
initially it was

```
 http://localhost:8080/gitlaboslcadaptor/oauth/callback
```

but the correct one should be

```
http://localhost:8080/gitlab.configuration/gitlaboslcadaptor/oauth/callback
```

this url should be correctly write in the gitlab account it self as well.